# Dimension of intersection of three spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, intuition, inclusion-exclusion

Axler's exercise 2.17 states the following.

> You might guess, by analagy with the formula for the number of elements in the union of three subsets of a finite set, that if $U_1$, $U_2$, $U_3$ are subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space, then
> \begin{align*}
> \dim(U_1 + U_2 + U_3) & = \dim U_1 + \dim U_2 + \dim U_3 \\
> & - \dim(U_1 \cap U_2) - \dim(U_1 \cap U_3) - \dim(U_2 \cap U_3) + \dim(U_1 \cap U_2 \cap U_3).
> \end{align*}
> Prove or give a counterexample.

I know for a fact that this statement is false and I don't have much trouble proving a counterexample. But I always have difficulty reasoning a-priori as to why a statement like this is true or false, which requires some level of intuition. When I look at this statement, I see the principle of inclusion-exclusion, which would lead me to the conclusion that it's true. I'm having difficulty understanding the intuition for why it's false.

Could anyone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: What's your counterexample? Like, the intuition can come from the counterexample. What is the novel feature of your counterexample that three generic subspaces won't have?

Comment: Inclusion/exclusion only works for finite sets. The dimensionality fails because the set of basis vectors is not typically finite.

Comment: @MikePierce: The counterexample I have is $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, $U_1 = \{(x,0)\}$, $U_2 = \{(0,y)\}$, $U_3 = \{(x,x)\}$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField: This is a very good point that I had not consider, but Axler's textbook doesn't usually consider infinite-dimensional vector spaces. Is the argument that the vector spaces themselves are probably infinite, so I can't just assert inclusion-exclusion? I'm trying to understand why this works in the $n = 2$, but not $n=3$, case.

Comment: @StanleySmith You can choose more than one set of distinct basis vectors for a finite dimensional spaces. I believe the fact that it works in $n=2$ is merely coincidence because of the low dimension. This happens a lot in algebra such as the fact that groups with order less than $6$ are all abelian but groups in general are not. Sometimes just being small makes certain properties emerge.

Comment: I understand that there are many different bases, but all of them contain a finite number of elements, right? I'm just trying to map this to the intuition of the sets not being finite. The vector spaces, as sets, are certainly not finite, so is that enough?

Comment: The comment above that the formula can fail because a basis might be infinite is not heading in the right direction. This exercise explicitly states that the context is that $U_1$, $U_2$, and $U_3$ are all subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space.